# bootstrap push/pull column with different height mobile vs desktop mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need help with the push/pull columns feature of Bootstrap.

I have 3 different sections that all can have **variable heights**.

On mobile mode, they have to be displayed vertically from 1 to 3 which is easy to do.

The issue is with the layout that I want to obtain on Desktop mode. My need for Desktop is to display them in 2 separate columns (50% each with col-md-6). On the left side I want sections 2, on the right side I want sections 1-3.

Mobile :

### Section 1

### Section 2

### Section 3

Desktop :

### Section 2       Section 1

### Nothing..       Section 3

My problem is that **when the height of Section 2 is taller than the Height of Section 1**, the Section 3 position itself BELOW the Section 2 (even if displayed on the right side). My need is to have the Section 3 to be just below Section 1, no matter what is the height of Section 2.

Thanks for any assistance you may bring.

Here is the code :

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        Section 1
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        Section 2
        <br />
        is taller than Section 1 with this 2nd line
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        Section 3 doesn't start right under Section 1
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you use something like `col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6` for the section 3 div? Offset it on medium and smaller sizes.

Comment: Please post the code you've attempted.

Comment: just added the code to the post